# Return Sub-document only when matched but keep empty arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection set with documents like :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57065ee93f0762541749574e"),
    "name": "myName",
    "results" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("570e3e43628ba58c1735009b"),
            "color" : "GREEN",
            "week" : 17,
            "year" : 2016
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("570e3e43628ba58c1735009d"),
            "color" : "RED",
            "week" : 19,
            "year" : 2016
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to build a query witch alow me to return all documents of my collection but only select the field 'results' with subdocuments if week > X and year > Y.

I can select the documents where week > X and year > Y with the aggregate function and a $match but I miss documents with no match.
So far, here is my function :

```
query = ModelUser.aggregate(
    {$unwind:{path:'$results', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},
    {$match:{
        $or: [
            {$and:[
                {'results.week':{$gte:parseInt(week)}},
                {'results.year':{$eq:parseInt(year)}}
            ]},
            {'results.year':{$gt:parseInt(year)}},
            {'results.week':{$exists: false}}
    {$group:{
        _id: {
            _id:'$_id',
            name: '$name'
        },
        results: {$push:{
            _id:'$results._id',
            color: '$results.color',
            numSemaine: '$results.numSemaine',
            year: '$results.year'
        }}
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: '$_id._id',
        name: '$_id.name',
        results: '$results'
);
```

The only thing I miss is : I have to get all 'name' even if there is no result to display.

Any idea how to do this without 2 queries ?

Comment: What are you really saying here? Is it that you basically always want to see results, but maybe just empty if nothing was a match? Meaning as opposed to just removing the whole document if there was no match? Because if you are expecting the document but not "results" field conditionally, then that's generally not a "practical" ask. But I think at least the "empty" array is a step up from where you are. What's your MongoDB server version? As it's very simple in latest releases.

Comment: Unfortunately my mongoDB server runs on 2.4

Comment: It's fine if the 'results' field is empty but I miss the part for that in mongoDB, especialy the way to test value in the subdocument in order to do something.

Comment: You say you are using MongoDB 2.4, yet your code shows `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option on `$unwind`. This was only introduced with MongoDB 3.2. So if the code works without producing a very loud error, you in fact have MongoDB 3.2. Then again, there are errors in your code, so it's questionable if you actually ran anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you actually have MongoDB 3.2, so use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the array. This will just return an "empty" array `[]` where the conditions supplied did not match anything:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "user": 1,
    "results": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$results",
        "as": "result",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": [ "$$result.year", year ] },
            { "$or": [
              { "$gt": [ "$$result.week", week ] },
              { "$not": { "$ifNull": [ "$$result.week", false ] } }
            ]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }          
  }}
])
```

Where the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) test in place of `$exists` as a logical form can actually "compact" the condition since it returns an alternate value where the property is not present, to:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "user": 1,
    "results": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$results",
        "as": "result",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": [ "$$result.year", year ] },
            { "$gt": [
                { "$ifNull": [ "$$result.week", week+1 ] },
                week
            ]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }          
  }}
])
```

In MongoDB 2.6 releases, you can probably get away with using [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) and `$$DESCEND`, but of course need to fake the match in the top level document. This has similar usage of the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$year", year ] }, year ] },
          { "$gt": [
            { "$ifNull": [ "$week", week+1 ] }
            week
          ]}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$DESCEND",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

If you actually have MongoDB 2.4, then you are probably better off filtering the array content in client code instead. Every language has methods for filtering array content, but as a JavaScript example reproducible in the shell:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.results = doc.results.filter(function(result) {
       return (
           result.year == year &&
           ( result.hasOwnProperty('week') ? result.week > week : true )
       )
    ]);
    printjson(doc);
})
```

The reason being is that prior to MongoDB 2.6 you need to use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and various stages in-between. This is a "very costly" operation on the server, considering that all you want to do is remove items from the arrays of documents and not actually "aggregate" from items within the array.

MongoDB releases have gone to great lengths to provide array processing that does not use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), since it's usage for that purpose alone is not a performant option. It should **only ever** be used in the case where you are removing a "significant" amount of data from arrays as a result.

The whole point is that otherwise the "cost" of the aggregation operation is likely greater than the "cost" of transferring the data over the network to be filtered on the client instead. Use with caution:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Create an array if one does not exist or is already empty
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "user": 1,
    "results": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$ifNull": [ "$results.0", false ] },
        "$results",
        [false]
      ]
    }
  }},
  // Unwind the array
  { "$unwind": "$results" },
  // Conditionally $push based on match expression and conditionally count
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "user": { "$first": "$user" },
    "results": {
      "$push": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$or": [
            { "$not": "$results" },
            { "$and": [
              { "$eq": [ "$results.year", year ] },
              { "$gt": [
                { "$ifNull": [ "$results.week", week+1 ] },
                week
              ]}
            ]}
          ] },
          "$results",
          false
        ]
      }
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$and": [
            { "$eq": [ "$results.year", year ] },
            { "$gt": [
              { "$ifNull": [ "$results.week", week+1 ] },
              week
            ]}
          ] }
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  // $unwind again
  { "$unwind": "$results" }
  // Filter out false items unless count is 0
  { "$match": { 
    "$or": [
      "$results",
      { "count": 0 }
    ]
  }},
  // Group again
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "_id",
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "user": { "$first": "$user" },
    "results": { "$push": "$results" }
  }},
  // Now swap [false] for []
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "user": 1,
    "results": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$ne": [ "$results", [false] ] },
        "$results",
        []
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Now that is a lot of operations and shuffling just to "filter" content from an array compared to all of the other approaches which are really quite simple. And aside from the complexity, it really does "cost" a lot more to execute on the server.

So if your server version actually supports the newer operators that can do this optimally, then it's okay to do so. But if you are stuck with that last process, then you probably should not be doing it and instead do your array filtering in the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot to provide this full answer.

Comment: I've messed up with my mongo version between dev and prod, but my production is on 2.4. I know, I should downgrade my development environment :)

After many try on mongo, I finally used the JS filtering method. It does perfectly my job and I hope it will be able to handle lots of data.

Anyway, I keep in mind the `$filter` for my future projects